# Postgres SQL using CTE when subtracting dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to subtract the current date depending on the integer result of a select statement from cte_film. However, putting the select statement inside the select now() interval is giving me issues.

```
WITH cte_film AS (
SELECT configvalue from TRAC.configvalues con where configcd = 'processingday'
),
cte_filma AS
(SELECT now() - (select configvalue from cte_film) * INTERVAL '1 day')
SELECT * from cte_filma;
```

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * interval
>   LINE 5: ...SELECT now() - (select configvalue from cte_film) *
>   INTERVAL...
>                                                                ^    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need     to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the issue?

Comment: I am trying to subtract the current date depending on the integer result of a select statement from cte_film

Comment: have you tried? `SELECT CURRENT_DATE - configvalue 
  FROM trac.configvalues con 
  WHERE configcd = 'processingday'` to sutract one day you can use, e.g. `CURRENT_DATE - 1` or with a date column `configvalue - 1`

Comment: That second CTE might be clearer if written as `cte_filma AS
(SELECT now() -  INTERVAL '1 day' * configvalue FROM cte_film)`

Answer (score 3):

I might be oversimplifying your issue, but as far as I understand you don't need a `CTE` at all. Try this:

```
SELECT now() - configvalue
FROM trac.configvalues 
WHERE configcd = 'processingday'
```

If you don't need the hours, use `current_date` instead of `now()`. See the difference:

```
SELECT current_date - 1, now() - '1 day'::INTERVAL;

  ?column?  |           ?column?            
------------+-------------------------------
 2020-03-11 | 2020-03-11 16:23:56.384132+01
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: `configvalue * INTERVAL '1 day'::INTERVAL` can further be simplified to `make_interval(days => configvalue)`

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd CTE like this:

```
WITH 
  cte_film AS (
    SELECT configvalue 
    FROM TRAC.configvalues
    WHERE configcd = 'processingday'
  ),
  cte_filma AS (
    SELECT now() - configvalue::int  * INTERVAL '1 day'::interval
    FROM cte_film
  )
SELECT * FROM cte_filma;
```

Comment: Hello, I am getting the following error when trying this out.

    ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * interval
    LINE 8:     SELECT now() - configvalue  * INTERVAL '1 day'::interval
                                        ^
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Isn't `configvalue` an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your inputs. I was able to solve the issue by using 
    `cte_filma AS (SELECT now() - INTERVAL '1 day'  configvalue FROM cte_film)`.

```
WITH cte_film AS (
SELECT configvalue from TRAC.configvalues con where configcd = 'processingday'
),
cte_filma AS (SELECT now() - INTERVAL '1 day' processingdate FROM cte_film),
maxi as (select max(workdt) as defaulterdatefrom from trac.defaulteraction)
SELECT DATE_PART('day', defaulterdatefrom::timestamp - processingdate::timestamp) as 
SourceCount from cte_film,cte_filma,maxi;
```

[image]

Comment: if you do not need the hours, consider using `current_date - 1`. Check my answer and @a_horse_with_no_name suggestion.

Comment: This solution is way too complicated